# SQL Query - Pull User Achievement

Tags: sql, informix

First, I am sorry as I could not come up with better title for this question.

I have a badge/achievement system in my website, community users are rewarded specific badges according to their activity in the website, below sql example I use to pull the number of users who made at at least 100 forum posts (I am using informix db version 10)

```
SELECT tjm.userid::INTEGER AS user_id, 
  EXTEND(DBINFO("UTC_TO_DATETIME",tjm.creationdate/1000), year to fraction) 
    AS earned_date
FROM TABLE(
  MULTISET(
    SELECT jm.userid, jm.creationdate, (
      SELECT COUNT(*) from TABLE(
        MULTISET(
          SELECT userid, creationdate
          FROM jive:jivemessage
        )
      ) AS i 
      WHERE i.userid = jm.userid AND i.creationdate < jm.creationdate
    ) + 1 AS row_num
    FROM jive:jivemessage jm 
  )
) AS tjm 
WHERE tjm.row_num=100
```

This sql takes around more than 30 minutes to execute, we have a very large community and there are millions of forum posts.

I would like to know if there is a solution to improve the query performance? I am trying to reduce the execution time because I have 40 sql queries similar to this one but for different tables and activities.

Comment: Unwind it, this query has 3 sub-queries -- at 100 records that is 100*100*100*100 rows which need to be processed, every sub-query you get rid of will save you 2 orders of magnitude.

Comment: @Hogan: I have a very limited knowledge in informix and SQL, can yo up please clarify what things I can do to improve it?

Comment: I don't know informix, so I'm not 100% comfortable with doing so, also this kind of complex query is a lot easier to work with when there is example data to verify against.  Grab a DBA and have him/her re-write your queries -- there is a lot of room to improve there.

Comment: @Hogan I definitely agree about having room for improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't now Informix DB, but the query below should do what you ask and it's ANSI SQL (except for the EXTEND part, which I copied from your original query).

```
SELECT
  jm.userid
  ,EXTEND(DBINFO("UTC_TO_DATETIME",tjm.creationdate/1000), year to fraction) AS earned_date
FROM
  (
  -- This sub-query will return all Users who have 100 messages or more
  SELECT
    jm.userid
    ,count(jm.userid) as totalmessages
  FROM
    jive:jivemessage jm
  GROUP BY
    jm.userid
  HAVING
    count(jm.userid) >= 100) AS MessageCount
```

The above could probably be done without having to use a sub-query. The only reason why I used it is to have the DateEarned, as per original query, in the result set. Adding it to the sub-query would have required adding it to the GROUP BY, with unpredictable results if the query runs across two days (e.g. at 23:59:59).

**Update 2012/08/14 - Rewritten query following new requirements**

As I stated before, I don't know Informix at all, therefore the following query may or may not run.

```
SELECT
  UsersWithBadge.userid
  ,MAX(UsersWithBadge.creationdate) as dateearned
FROM
  (
  SELECT FIRST 100
    jm.userid
    ,jm.creationdate
  FROM
    jive:jivemessage jm
    JOIN
    (-- This sub-query will return all Users who have 100 messages or more
    SELECT
      jm.userid
      ,count(jm.userid) as totalmessages
    FROM
      jive:jivemessage jm
    GROUP BY
      jm.userid
    HAVING
      count(jm.userid) >= 100)
    AS MessageCount ON
      (MessageCount.userid = jm.userid)
  ) AS UsersWithBadge     
GROUP BY
  UsersWithBadge.userid
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I was using this in the past, but we changed to use the sql I posted in my original question because of one thing (I forgot to mention in my question) that we want to retrieve the creationdate of the record that was created when user reached specific number of posts, for example, the user made a forum post in July, 1st, 2012. That post was the 100th for that user, we want to retrieve that date as the date the user earned the badge. Why we are doing this because we were late in implementing badges system for our website and we want to recursively pull dates from past

Comment: This complicates things significantly, I wouldn't expect the query to be fast anyway. I updated my answer, check if it might help.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the problem in your query is that it will return the max date of all returned records, for example, if I have 100th forum posts and I want to get the date of my 50th forum post, then it will return the date of the 100th forum post, not 50th. Also I had to remove *FIRST 100* to make it work

Comment: @AhmadAlkhawaja What the query with "FIRST 100" does is retrieving User's first 100 posts and finding the newest one (i.e. the 100th, as your original request was to find when User reached 100 posts). If you remove that clause, of course it will always return the latest post, which is not what you asked.

Comment: About the new clause you added, "find the 50th post": that would simply be a matter of replacing FIRST 100 with FIRST 50, and you'd get the date of each User's 50th post. Sure, it's a manual operation, but, as you wrote, you're doing this once to compensate for the lack of this feature in your original software, therefore it should not be a big deal to manually run a couple of queries.